# Android saving file to memory card

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, jsch

In the below program i get the exception as shown below.Basically what  i am trying to do is i am copying a file from a remote system to the device.but when saving to the memory card both on the emulator and device i am hitting an exception.The below exception is from the emulator where i can say that the memory card is not attached to the emulator and so the exception.but will the code work for a physical device.

How to make the code work on emulator and the device

Exception:

```
 09-13 15:47:16.789: I/System.out(400): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Download/new.txt (Not a directory)
```

Code:

```
package com.scp2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import com.jcraft.jsch.*;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Scp2Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = null;
            try {
                session = jsch.getSession("guest", "17.30.5.2", 22);

                session.connect();
                Toast.makeText(this,  "in try2" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                channel.connect();
                ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
                File ofile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"new.txt");
                Toast.makeText(this, ofile.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   try {
                    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(ofile);
                  sftpChannel.get("/root/a.txt","/mnt/sdcard/download/dd.txt");
                  /*OR What shoud the abobe statement be **/
              //sftpChannel.get("/root/a.txt",ofile); or this statement is correct

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                         System.out.println(e.toString());
                }


                sftpChannel.exit();
                session.disconnect();
            } catch (JSchException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 

            } catch (SftpException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }


    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this for file creation ; a better and safer way than yours

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Downloads/");
dir.mkdirs();
String strFileName = "dd.html";
File file = new File(dir,strFileName);
```

Comment: But how will i pull the remote file from sftpChannel.get() and use your given code?

Comment: you should replace `/mnt/sdcard/download/dd.txt` with `file` after using my code

Comment: k when i use sftpChannel.get("/home/guest/a.txt",file); i get an error saying The method get(String, String) in the type ChannelSftp is not applicable for the arguments (String, File)

Comment: sorry, you should replace `/mnt/sdcard/download/dd.txt` with `file.getAbsolutePath();` after using my code

Comment: k the code compiles without any errors but on the emulator i still dont see anything in the downloads folder not sure what the issue is

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16637/discussion-between-rajeev-and-mojo)

Comment: did you made any changes or ran on a diff version?